# ExtJS filter function working on one combobox but not another?

Tags: extjs, combobox, null, extjs6-classic

I am working on a project that requires me to filter a combobox down as the user types.  I have it set up so that I have a helper function that should be a general purpose combobox function:

```
filterComboGeneral: function(combo, filterfield)
{
    // try
    // {
        console.log(combo.getXType());
        var passpatt = '^' + combo.getValue().toLowerCase();

        if (combo.store.isFiltered())
        {
            combo.store.clearFilter();
        }

        combo.store.filterBy(function(record) {


            var pattern = new RegExp(passpatt);
            var teststr = record.get(filterfield).toLowerCase();

            var retval = pattern.test(teststr);


            return retval;
        });
    // }
    // catch (e) {
    //     console.log("null was encountered in text box.  Moving on");
    // }
}
```

Please ignore the commented try-catch I commented them to check what exception was actually being thrown.

I then have a specific function that calls this general function:

```
filterMainCombo: function(combo, release)
{
    this.filterComboGeneral(combo, "name");
}
```

I then have two comboboxes.  The first is defined in the view file:

```
{
      xtype: 'combobox',
      itemId: 'scriptfilt',
      store: {
          type: 'scriptstore'
      },
      valueField: 'id',
      displayField: 'name',
      typeAhead: true,
      autoSelect: true,
      minChars: 1,
      typeAheadDelay: 0,
      enableKeyEvents: true,
      listeners: {
          keyUp: 'filterMainCombo'
      }
  }
```

This combo box works perfectly fine.

Then I have another one that is declared as a variable in my controller file (which is by the way the same file my filter functions are in):

```
var scriptcb = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Script',
        store: scrstore,
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'id',
        forceSelection: true,
        itemId: 'scriptcombo',
        typeAhead: true,
        autoSelect: true,
        minChars: 1,
        typeAheadDelay: 0,
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        listeners: {
            keyUp: 'filterMainCombo'
        }
    });
```

This combobox then gets added to a window which is displayed.  But for some reason whenever I go to type actual values in the second box described here, the keyUp event is fired but the value is null and not sure why.

Comment: I found the reason.  I commented out the `forceSelection: true` line and it's perfectly fine.  

Does anyone know the specifics on why this is?

Comment: Check this documentation http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-forceSelection.

If forceSelection: true will set a value to combo only if value you are trying to set is present in Combo store. And if its false. you can set value to Combo even if its not present in its store.

Comment: If you preload the store (using store.load() or autoLoad: true) and set the combobox.queryMode to local, a filter is automatically added as you type.